# How to work abroad?

Tags: work-life-balance

I am Chinese, I don't know English. I want to study English while working abroad. I am a chef in China. I have sent about 200 resumes to foreign companies. No company hires me. I just want to do a minimum. The job, even if it is cutting potatoes, is it impossible to have a job without English?

I know that my current thinking is a bit of a mystery. I wanted to learn English two years ago. In China, I need to work twelve hours a day. There is no English environment, so I always want to study English abroad. Why did my resume show that I can do the lowest level of work, work twelve hours a day, and no company is willing to hire me.

Comment: Which countries are you applying to, and are you legally entitled to work in those countries? Nobody's going to do visa sponsorship for an entry level chef.

Comment: So if you don't know English who wrote this question? If you don't understand English, how are you going to understand the answer?

Comment: @Kilisi: He could have asked a friend to post it?

Comment: yes. it's a somehow reasonable question, nothing close to what could be considered a troll question. What would be the 'fun' part of the question if it was a troll?

Comment: @FooBar I'd be more convinced if the OP answered not you... no offense.

Comment: @Kilisi If I'm honest the question looks very google translate.

Answer (score 8):

It's not just about the language which definitely you can can start learning in your spare time.

The problem is VISA. Will a company sponsor your VISA for a low profile job? Someone capable to do the *"...lowest level of work, work twelve hours a day..."* can be found anywhere without all the hassle that comes from VISA sponsorship.

If you want to move to another country then, together with the language, you should work on your skill set, you must offer something they can't find elsewhere. Why should they pick *you* instead of someone else who is already there?

You may also start looking for an apprenticeship to get a foot in and to gain some experience (Chinese chef with experience in, let's say, French sweets?)

Answer (score 3):

Learn English while you're where you are now.

Look on the internet, look for books, ask friends and family about resources to help you learn English.

There are a lot of ways to learn English, and you should be able to do this in your spare time.

Answer (score 2):

In England there are plenty Chinese restaurants that only hire Chinese staff, on and off the books. I have personally experienced that if you get in touch with a big enough company there are people that will sponsor a visa for an authentic Chinese chef depending on how good you are.

It is very unlikely for a takeaway to take you on as the costs of a visa outweigh the profits that they can generate.